# JavaMail No Content error when downloading attachments from emails

Tags: java, android, email, jakarta-mail, imap

I'm developing an Android application which is basically an Email client. I can connect to the remote server and fetch Emails perfectly, but whenever I try to download an attachment it just simply echos the following:

```
 java.io.IOException: No content at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPInputStream.fill(IMAPInputStream.java:159)
```

The attachment is `AUDIO/AMR` and the output says the content is

```
    com.sun.mail.util.BASE64DecoderStream@431255d8
```

If anyone is wondering, I'm trying to download VoiceMail from the Vodafone IMAP server.
If you would like to test it yourself the settings are as followed, username is `614xxxxxxxx@vm.vodafone.net.au` where you substitute the x's for your number, the password is your 4 digit VoiceMail PIN , the host is `vvm.vodafone.com.au` and the `port is 993`.

Here is some of the code I have currently:

```
public void GetVoicemail() throws Exception {
    Session session = Session.getInstance(SetProperties(), null);
    Store store = session.getStore();
    store.connect(_host, 993, _user, _pass);
    Folder inbox = store.getFolder("INBOX");
    inbox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
    System.out.println("Emails: " + inbox.getMessageCount());
    Message msg = inbox.getMessage(1);
    Address[] froms = msg.getFrom();
    String email = froms == null ? null : ((InternetAddress) froms[0]).getAddress();
    File test = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/test.amr");

    Multipart multiPart = (Multipart) msg.getContent();
    for (int i = 0; i < multiPart.getCount(); i++) {
        MimeBodyPart part = (MimeBodyPart) multiPart.getBodyPart(i);
        System.out.println("Part: " + part.getContentType());
        if (part.getContentType().equalsIgnoreCase("AUDIO/AMR")) {
            System.out.println(part.getContent());
            System.out.println(part.getEncoding());
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(part.getInputStream()));
            String inputLine;
            while ((inputLine = in .readLine()) != null)
                System.out.println(inputLine); in .close();
        }
    }
    //Msg temp = new Msg(GetBuffer(msg.getContent()), email, msg.getSentDate());
    //Main.messages.add(temp);
    /*
            Multipart multipart = (Multipart) msg.getContent();    
                for(int i = 0; i < multipart.getCount(); i++){
                BodyPart bodyPart = multipart.getBodyPart(i);           
                InputStream is = bodyPart.getInputStream();
                File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/test.amr");
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
                byte[] buf = new byte[4096];
                int bytesRead;
                while((bytesRead = is.read(buf))!=-1) {
                fos.write(buf, 0, bytesRead);
            }
            fos.close();
        }
        */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the mail server is broken.

Can you post the [JavaMail debug output](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug) when you try to access the attachment?

You might have to use [this technique](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#imapserverbug) to work around the broken server.

Comment: Hi, here is the output which strangely contains the Base64 String which I was able to convert online to binary and it was playable!

Comment: First, you're using an old version of JavaMail, so the debug output includes your (encoded but not encrypted) password in the AUTHENTICATE PLAIN response.  Change your password immediately.

Comment: You're reading the voicemail data as if it was text.  It almost certainly is not.  Use the [technique described in the JavaMail FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#readattach) to read and save the attachment data.